# Why OpenLayers does not render the features collection?

Tags: openlayers

I use this code:

```
 const source = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSONOl(),
      strategy: bboxStrategy,
    });
    source.addFeatures(features);

    const layer = new VectorLayer({
      source,
    });

    map.addLayer(layer);
```

Where `features` is geojson collection:

[image]

There is not error and geometry on the map

Also I tried this way:

```
 const source = new VectorSource({
      format: new GeoJSONOl(),
      strategy: bboxStrategy,
      loader: (extent: Extent, resolution: number, projection) => {
        const geoJSONFormat = new GeoJSONOl();
        const features = geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(geojson);
        source.addFeatures(features);
      },
    });

    const layer = new VectorLayer({
      source,
    });

    map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: `VectorSource` needs either a `url` or `loader`

Comment: What if I dont have url but have a object? I have tried this: `features: new GeoJSONOl().readFeatures(features),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have an object just read it and create the source with features

```
   const source = new VectorSource({
     features: geoJSONFormat.readFeatures(geojson, {featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection()});
   });
```

Most likely the features are not where you expected if the map and json are in different projections